# How to apply validation of a Model which is having a ref?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to apply validation on the current schema.What is the way I can validate using validator and show error message when the projectMembers is not entered?

```
projectMembers: [{
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
            required: true,
        },
        userRole: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'UserRole',
            required: true,
        },
    }],
```

User Model

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        validate: {
            validator: (username) => {
                return username.length >= 3
            },
            msg: () => {
                return 'UserName length less than 3 characters'
            }
        }
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        minlength: 7,
        validate: {
            validator: (email) => {
                return validator.isEmail(email)
            },
            msg: () => {
                return 'Enter a valid email'
            }
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 8,
        validate: {
            validator: (password) => {
                return password.length >= 8
            }
        },
        msg: function () {
            return 'Enter atleast 8 charcters'
        }
    })
```

UserRole Model

```
const UserRoleSchema = new Schema({
    userRole: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: {
            validator: (userRole) => {
                return userRole.length >= 0
            },
            msg: () => {
                return 'User Role should be selected'
            }
        }
    }
})

const UserRole = mongoose.model('UserRole', UserRoleSchema)
module.exports = UserRole
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let' say your projectMembers is inside a model called Project.

You can set required error message in schema like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const projectSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  projectMembers: [
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: [true, "User is required"]
      },
      userRole: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "UserRole",
        required: [true, "User Role is required"]
      }
    }
  ]
});

const Project = mongoose.model("Project", projectSchema);

module.exports = Project;
```

And in post project route, you can use mongoose's doc.validateSync()  method to validate.

Here is a sample:

```
router.post("/project", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, projectMembers } = req.body;

  const project = new Project({ name, projectMembers });

  const { errors } = project.validateSync();

  if (errors) {
    let convertedErrors = [];
    for (field in errors) {
      convertedErrors.push(errors[field].message);
    }

    return res.send({ errors: convertedErrors });
  }

  //todo: do whatever you want

  res.send();
});
```

If you send a request without user role to this route with this body:

```
{
 "name": "project name",
 "projectMembers": [{
    "user": "5dc12a0aa875cd0ca8b871ea"
 }] 
}
```

You will get this response:

```
{
    "errors": [
        "User Role is required"
    ]
}
```

And if you send a request without user role and user to this route with this body:

```
{
 "name": "project name",
 "projectMembers": [{}] 
}
```

You will get this response:

```
{
    "errors": [
        "User Role is required",
        "User is required"
    ]
}
```

Comment: @Biswajeetgope can you add User and UserRole models, and your route to the question?

Comment: @Biswajeetgope can you also add schema where projectMembers  is in?

Comment: @Biswajeetgope I updated the answer with the post route.  If this does not help you, can you add to your question your model where projectMembers resides and  your route code?